Rename JSONB key that have a wildcard postgresql
Is it possible to rework a JSONB object using a wildcard?
I have a model like this:
{
    "shelves": {
        "07665516-1e34-40a5-8cc1-907b754309c0": {
            "reference_face": {
                "families": [
                    {
                        ...
                    }
            }
    }


And I would like to rename "families" into "products" for each entry in the "shelves" list.
Unfortunately the key "07665516-1e34-40a5-8cc1-907b754309c0" is an auto generated uuid and I do not find a way to use a wildcard in my update request.
I tried:
UPDATE "products"
 SET "implantation" = jsonb_set("implantation" #- '{shelves,%*%,reference_face,families}',
'{shelves,%*%,reference_face,products}',
"implantation"#>'{shelves,'jsonb_each_text',reference_face,families}')
where "implantation"#>'{shelves,%*%,reference_face}' ? 'families';

But it does not change anything... the '*' does not work...
I tried also using jsonb_path_query:
UPDATE "products"
 SET "implantation" = jsonb_set(jsonb_path_query("implantation", '$.shelves.*.reference_face'),
'{shelves,.*,reference_face,products}',
"store_product_implantation"#>jsonb_path_query("implantation", '$.shelves.*.reference_face'))
where "implantation"#>'{shelves}' is not null;

However I get an error... "set-returning functions are not allowed in UPDATE"
Is there any way to put a wildcard while renaming a JSON key?
2 - Second possibilities
Another way to handle this would be to set the uuid in a dedicated field but I don't know if it's possible to. The model would be like that:
{
    "shelves": [
            "uuid": "07665516-1e34-40a5-8cc1-907b754309c0",
            "reference_face": {
                "products": [
                    {
                        ...
                    }
            ]
    }


